# Let the shell parse or do your own parsing (powershell/cmd)

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd, arguments

I develop an application with command line parameters and use it in cmd shell and powershell. There it is obvious that the arguments are received differently in main() of my application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // In cmd shell:  args[0] == "-ipaddress=127.0.0.1"
  // In powershell: args[0] == "-ipaddress=127"
  //            and args[1] == ".0.0.1"
}
```

Example:
myApp.exe -ipaddress=127.0.0.1

In my C# application the arguments are interpreted differently depending on the shell I start the app in.

- In cmd shell: arg[0]=-ipaddress=127.0.0.1
- In powershell: arg[0]=-ipaddress=127 and arg[1]=.0.0.1

What is best practice here?

- Should I join all args[] and parse the arguments in my application?
- Should I rely on the shell's parser?

Comment: Closely related PSv2 variation of the bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49118108/45375

Answer (score 0):

I would abandon cmd shell support completely and just created proper PowerShell cmdlet. [Writing a Windows PowerShell Cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878294.aspx). But I don't know your exact requirements.

In general calling executable from cmd and PowerShell should work same way. For example line, "> ping -n 3 google.com" just works fine no matter where you put it.

Comment: Do you have a source for the latter? Is it a general requirement that commands should be copy pasted regardless of their shell?

Comment: This is how it work https://i.imgur.com/3kM4DoW.png
PS resolves commands in this order: Alias, Function, Cmdlet, Native Windows commands.
More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-6#command-precedence

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**:

When calling **from PowerShell, enclose the entire argument in `'...'`** (single quotes) to ensure that it is passed as-is:

```bash
myApp.exe '-ipaddress=127.0.0.1'
```

**Alternatively, `` ` ``-escape the initial `-`**:

```bash
myApp.exe `-ipaddress=127.0.0.1
```

---

You've run into a **parsing bug**<sup>[1]</sup>
where **PowerShell breaks an unquoted argument that starts with `-` in *two* at the first `.`**

The following simplified example demonstrates that:

```bash
# Helper function that echoes all arguments.
function Out-Argument { $i = 0; $Args | % { 'arg[{0}]: {1}' -f ($i++), $_ }}

# Pass an unquoted argument that starts with "-" and has an embedded "."
Out-Argument -foo=bar.baz
```

The above yields:

```bash
arg[0]: -foo=bar
arg[1]: .baz
```

---

<sup>[1] The presumptive *bug* is present as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / and up to at least PowerShell (Core) v7.3.6 and has been reported [in GitHub issue #6291](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291).

A *PSv2* variation of the bug affects `.` *when enclosed in `"..."`* in the *interior* of the argument - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49118620/45375).</sup>