# Execute external command with single-hypen parameter with equals and period

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a tool that accepts parameters like this (e.g. in `test.ps1`):

```
foo.exe -name="john"
```

So, each parameter is specified with a single hyphen `-`, the name, an equals `=`, and then the value of the parameter.

When I invoke this exact expression from PowerShell, it executes without any problems. However, when one of the values contains a period `.` like this:

```
foo.exe -name="john.doe"
```

Running it causes a syntax error:

> $ ./test.ps1 The string starting: At
>   test.ps1:1
>   char:24
>   + foo.exe -name="john.doe <<<< " is missing the terminator: ". At test.ps1:1
>   char:25
>   + foo.exe -name="john.doe" <<<<
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:String) [], ParseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Some ways that I can prevent PowerShell from interpreting this are:

- `` foo.exe "-name=`"john.doe`"" ``
- `foo.exe '-name="john.doe"'`
- PowerShell V3+: `foo.exe --% -name="john.doe"`
- `$nameArg = "john.doe"; foo.exe -name="$nameArg"`

However, some of these options prevent interpolation of variables. Are there other ways to stop PowerShell from causing syntax issues? In this specific instance (adding the period), why is PowerShell having issues interpreting this?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you include the path to the exe?

Comment: All you need is `foo.exe "-name=john.doe"`.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is **a *bug*** in PSv2; in short: an argument that *starts* with *unquoted* `-` breaks parsing if it also contains a `.` *within `"..."`*.

<sup>A **milder variation** of the bug **still exists in PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.1**; it has been [reported on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6291). Now, a `.` inside `"..."` works fine, but **an *unquoted* `.` actually breaks the argument in *two*.** The workaround below is also effective for said variation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021910/45375) of mine.</sup>

The **workaround** is to **quote the *entire* argument**:

```
# Use '...' instead if you don't need interpolation
foo.exe "-name=john.doe"
```

<sup>Note that there is typically *no* need to quote the *value* part individually - that is, to the *target program*,

`-name="john.doe 1"` is usually the same as `"-name=john.doe 1"`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, and I don't know if it is the best way to get around it but one way that I have done it before was to build the command string to execute and then execute it using `Invoke-Expression`.

```
$MyCommand = '& foo.exe --% -name="{0}"' -f 'john.doe'
Invoke-Expression $MyCommand
```

Or, more specific to my issue, I would have several arguments that would change that I had in a hashtable, so I would add those to the command. In context to your command I might have:

```
$MyArgs = @{
    name = 'john.doe'
    request = 'delete file'
    argument = '\jdoe\temp\nsfwstash.zip'
}
$MyCommand = '& foo.exe --%'
$MyArgs.Keys | ForEach{
    $MyCommand = $MyCommand + (' {0}="{1}"' -f $_, $MyArgs[$_])
}
Invoke-Expression $MyCommand
```

That would end up invoking a command that read:

```
& foo.exe --% -name="john.doe" -request="delete file" -argument="\jdoe\temp\nsfwstash.zip"
```